# Linux Security/Sysadmin Courses in London?

Tags: linux, security, unix

My employer has offered to send me on a couple of training courses and I'm just looking for some recommendations.

I'm mainly looking to improve my security and general sysadmin skills. I would like to do something focused on UNIX as I mainly work with Linux boxes (but also a couple of FreeBSD boxes).

I don't want to do a study-from-home course, so I would need to find somewhere based in London.

It would be great to hear from anyone who has some experience with this kind of course.

The courses I've found so far are:

www.learningtree.co.uk/courses/uk433.htm

www.city.ac.uk/cae/cfa/computing/systems_it/linux.html

www.city.ac.uk/cae/cfa/computing/systems_it/unix_tools_ss.html

I'm not sure the City University courses are advanced enough as I already have experience...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm dredging this topic back up as I've still not got round to taking a course. Does anyone have an opinion on CompTIA (Security+ and Linux+)? Basically, I'm just looking for something that will be good in the long term, looks good on my CV etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the official RedHat course+certification? It might be a bit pricey for an individual, but if the company is paying... :)

Check them out http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhce/

I link to RHCE, but check around, there are links to other courses. You might want to start with RHCT, depending on your experience. Don't take the rapid course though! It is only useful as a refresher and cover way too much in a very short amount of time.

Comment: I would check lpi as well  
www.lpi.org.   
There're different levels and some partner in London

Comment: Thanks for they replies!

Yeah, the RedHat training looks pretty good. It is quite pricey though.. We'll see what the boss has to say about it :-)

Not sure whether I'll be best off starting with RHCT or maybe just doing some self-study and moving straight on to RHCE.

Anyone know how RedHat specific these courses are? I mainly run Ubuntu servers (although I do run a couple of CentOS boxes). I'm hoping to gain some skills that we transferrable across different distros.

Comment: fairly redhat specific. If you get a RHCE exam book from amazon you can see the material they cover. Some of it is general topics such as grub etc, but some is rpm specific, and some more goes into detail on the redhat gui configuration tools etc. As i understand it the RHCE is fairly hard as certs go, but worth it.

Answer (score 0):

[QA](http://www.qa.com/) has the Red Hat courses and a bunch of other Linux ones in London.  If you want something more generic, I'd look at taking some [SANS](http://www.sans.org/london-2010/) courses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an eye on security and such, perhaps consider a CEH cert. It'd give you a fairly unique set of skills in the workplace, and perhaps aid employability in the future if you want to move into the security disiplines. I was asked several times for the CEH when i looked into penitration testing.